# AWS Glue - Tracking Processed Data on DocumentDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-documentdb

I have a DocumentDB as the data source.

I am running an AWS Glue job that pulls all the data from a certain table, and then inserts it to a RedShift cluster.

Is it possible to avoid adding duplicate data?

I have seen that [AWS glue supports bookmarks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html#monitor-continuations-implement),

This does not seem to work for DocumentDB as the data source

Thanks.